# Arcpy PointGeometry does not carry forward the ID

Tags: python, arcpy, point

[I used this as starting point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/PointGeometry/018z00000039000000)

I have the following code:

Test data

```
data = numpy.array([(0, 51.1047664, -114.3722785, 1205, 'I:\\0_Tools\\Testing\\gis\\disciplines\\aerial_imagery\\Agisoft_Automation\\ImageProcessing\\Test_Images\\Small\\2014-05-07-Bragg-0001.JPG'),
                             (1, 51.104791, -114.3755528, 1209, 'I:\\0_Tools\\Testing\\gis\\disciplines\\aerial_imagery\\Agisoft_Automation\\ImageProcessing\\Test_Images\\Small\\2014-05-07-Bragg-0002.JPG'),
                             (2, 51.10452519998783, -114.39971750000001, 1372, 'I:\\0_Tools\\Testing\\gis\\disciplines\\aerial_imagery\\Agisoft_Automation\\ImageProcessing\\Test_Images\\Small\\2014-05-07-Bragg-0003.JPG')],
                            dtype=([('Id', 'int'), ('SHAPE@X', '<f8'), ('SHAPE@Y', '<f8'), ('SHAPE@Z', 'int'), ('Path', 'S255')]))

pointGeometryList = []
        for pt in lat_long_data:
            point = arcpy.Point(pt[2], pt[1], None, None, int(pt[0]))
            print point.X 
            print point.ID
            point.ID = pt[0]
            pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, spatial_ref)
            pointGeometryList.append(pointGeometry)

        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointGeometryList, "c:/temp/points2")
```

When run the print.X and print.ID statements print the expected result, however when I look at the output table the ID is 0 across all records, I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Point (geometry) object won't carry forward values for other columns. It'll let you set it but it gets ignored. It seems you're expecting the geometry object to act like the Row object from the old cursor objects.

Why don't you skip the geometry list step and just use [`arcpy.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/NumPyArrayToFeatureClass/018w0000001n000000/)  to go straight from array to feature class?

Comment: Thanks I'll look at using arcpy.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass

Comment: Sounds like a different issue altogether, I'm unable to reproduce. You probably want to change `"c:/temp/points2"` to something like `"c:/temp/points2.shp"`. Also sometimes there are weird permissions set on `C:\TEMP` so try another folder.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Scheirer . I got it working with NumPyArray. Do you Is it possible to have it held in memory versus actually writing to a file?

Comment: This runs however output is empty

fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory", "fc_test", "POINT")
  arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(lat_long_data, fc, ('Y', 'X'), spatial_ref)
#Just to see result
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, out_path)

Comment: Don't do that. Just do `arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(lat_long_data, out_path, ('Y', 'X'), spatial_ref)`. You don't need any intermediate step.